# How can i access folder outside the root of codeigniter without passing sensitive information in the url?

Tags: codeigniter

My code (view) So far everything is working well when am accessing a folder(uploads) withing the root, but i would like to access a folder located in a different location withing the same server without showing sensitive information in the url when the image loads.

```
   <img src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/'.$popular_car['img_path'])?>" class="card-img-top" 
   style="height: 150px;"></div>
```

Comment: Good question. There's many many ways to do that. I just posted a rough description of how I solved this same thing. It's a little convoluted but has worked fine for me

Comment: is upload folder placed outside application folder ??

Comment: yes its actually on a different location within the same server

Answer (score 0):

There's many alternatives. Most will involve some sort of database use. This is what I do (greatly summarized)

Every file that will need to be accessed has a record on a table. The record has a primary id, a secret random token and the path to the file. The table is indexed by both the primary ID and the token.

On the URL I get something like `base_url('controller/file_access/).$id.'/'.$token`. Upon receiving the request, I'll check the files table, if there's a match for both parameters, I'll stream the file to the browser. This way of doing things, albeit a little bit more complicated, has two main benefits:

1.- it prevents a user to just try different numeric IDs and see what is displayed. Since IDs are numeric and autoincrementing, all you'd need to do is looping from 1 to 100000 and download all files. Adding the token and querying the table with both parameters greatly reduces the risk of someone getting a file he/she's not intended to.

2.- it obscures the real location of the file, as streaming it to the browser in this way looks (in the eyes of the browser) as being located in `example.com/controller/file_access/id/token` but the real or relative path to the image remains hidden and non-accessible from the web.

Using this as a base you can add a lot of logic on top of this depending on your needs. You could also have an "allowed_user" field in the table if files are private and/or user-specific so that you don't stream the file if the user is not allowed to see it (even if he has the correct ID/token combination).

This is just a rough description of what I do on a couple of sites. Take it as the theoretical foundation you can build on.